# Required not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The required in "brand" doesn't work and I don't know why.

View:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@equipment) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :brand, required:true,:label => "test" %>
```

Controller:

```
params.require(:equipment)
  .permit(:brand, :acquisition_year, :energy_label)
```

Model:

```
validates_presence_of :brand, :message => "brand"
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What happens that should not be happening? What error message do you get (if any)?

Answer (score 1):

Try without brackets in the form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @equipment do |f| %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :brand, required: true, label: 'test' %>
  </div>
  [...]
<% end >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= f.input :brand, required: true, label: "test" %>
```

See an empty space on 'true'

Comment: What happens when you submit the form? Do you have anything in your logs?